# algolia search box: how to add filters within searchbox

Tags: algolia

I am using lagolia and have categorie field in the record added as facet and also location field

I want to create a search box something like

[image]

How can i do this

Answer (score 0):

With both of those, the easiest way is going to be to use [InstantSearch.js](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/what-is-instantsearch/js/) and the built-in widgets.

For the Categories, you'll use the [`refinementList` widget](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/refinement-list/js/). This will pull the categories based on the attribute name for the data. You can use the `templates` property to define how the categories get displayed.

GeoSearch will always be a bit trickier. To do this with InstantSearch, you'll want to refine your search based on Latitude and Longitude. You can create a custom parameter to be inserted into the search when search is run. To do that, you'll customize the searchBox widget with the [`queryHook` parameter](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/search-box/js/#widget-param-queryhook). In the query hook, you can add the [`aroundLatLng` parameter](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/aroundLatLng/?client=javascript) to your search.

Comment: sorry can you show some outline for reactjs and algolia